# Symfony: temporarily storing a count

Tags: php, symfony

We have a system where you can enter your email address. Now, we want that if you request 3 times in a row (without success) that a special value is reported back.

Everything is working, except how to store the count of tries. We're working with Api-Platform.

This means that a Symfony Session should not do the trick. It will probably restart and create a new session after every request.

So, how can we store a count? Here is an example of what we try to achieve with the usage of Symfony Sessions. Any ideas how to store the count? Sessions weren't possible (Maybe wrong implementation) and a database table seems to be a bit excessive.

```
if(!$session->has('c_tries')) {
    $captchaTries = $session->set('c_tries', 0);
}

$captchaTries = $session->get('c_tries');

$new = $captchaTries + 1;
$session->set('c_tries', $new);

if($captchaTries > 2 ) {
....
```

Comment: table is alright, cache might be better (since it resets after some time). you could hash the email-address to get rid of weird chars and other stuff. you might use the hash as cache key, which is probably best. symfony has a cache component if i'm not mistaken. session won't really work, since you correctly assume that a user might just reset the session. also with api, there usually is no session.

Answer (score 0):

It is best to solve this on the client side. You can use cookies.

```
if (!isset($_COOKIE('trakcer']))) {
    setcookie ("TryCount", $captchaTries, time() + 3600); /*expires in 1 hour*/
  }
```

Comment: sessions and cookies are essentially the same in that it relies on the client to behave properly. malicious users don't, especially if it's automated. where is your approach better than the approach op already got?